# Insert a plot image inside table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm very new in MATLAB and I'm trying to do the following: I've 5 images and I want to create a table with names and some statistics as columns. In addition, I would like to insert one column in which every cell is the histogram of the images.
My code is this:

```
Type = {'volto';'volto_jpg'; 'volto_jpg_100';'volto_tiff';'volto_tiff_nocompression'}
Sum_of_diff = [NaN;2531547;280391;0;0]
Medie = cellfun(@mean2,y)
Dev_st = cellfun(@std2,y)
x = table(Type; Sum_of_diff; Medie; Dev_st)
```

I would like to add a final column where i can view the histogram made with `imhist()` function.
It could be possible? Of course only for exporting and visualising purposes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). First things first, IMHO, you should absolutely avoid having capitals starting your variables names. Second, could be a lit clearer on what you want, instead of just saying ` want to create a table with names and some statistics as columns`.

Comment: @Paradox Sorry for my mistakes and thanks for suggestions. I mean that the `x` table that I've created have the purpose to contain some statistics. I've already done it with `cellfun(@mean2,y)` and `cellfun(@std2,y)` functions. My question is about the possibility to add another column to my `x` table with an image in each row. These pictures should be the histograms of every images i've considered in my table.

Comment: Do you want it to contain the data for a histogram, the handle to a figure window with the histogram, and image of the plot, ... ?